# Button ClickEvent not triggered when textArea onFocus

Tags: angular, typescript, onclick, buttonclick

I need to trigger button ClickEvent when focusing on textArea input.
PS : My textArea with some styles when it's focused it becomes maximized

The example is below :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zy9sqj?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you click on the `button` your `textarea` loses focus and returns back to it's initial `height`, which is why the click gets missed. You must somehow not let the `textarea` go back to it's initial `height` as soon it loses focus, or maybe delay it, so that the button gets clicked first.

One approach would be to set the textarea height to its maximized height when the button is hovered, using the JavaScript `mouseover` event.

And, once the button is clicked, change it back to its initial height.

See if the below workaround works for you!

HTML:

```
<textarea id="text">test</textarea> <br/>
<button id="button">Change</button>
```

CSS:

```
textarea{
  height: 100px; /* initial height */
}    
textarea:focus {
  height: 200px; /* maximized height */
}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('#button')
        .addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.querySelector('#text').value += 'changed';
            document.querySelector('#text').style.height = '100px';
});

document.querySelector('#button')
        .addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
            document.querySelector('#text').style.height = '200px';
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ew86fb5p/

hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your idea.
I added the "hover" option for the textarea and it works !

Comment: here the example 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zy9sqj?file=src/app/app.component.css